# Cursor not open

Tags: sql, sap-iq

I'm trying to create table using statements stored in table. I'm using a cursor with execute(sql) as below:

```
create table tab
(
  CreateSql varchar(250)
)

insert into tab values ('create table tab1 (id int )')
insert into tab values ('create table tab2 (id int )')
insert into tab values ('create table tab3 (id int )')

  declare cur cursor for
    select createsql
      from tab  

  declare @sql varchar(255)

  open cur
  fetch cur into @sql

  while @@SqlStatus = 0
    begin           
      execute(@Sql)               
      fetch cur into @sql
    end

  close cur
  deallocate cursor cur
```

If I run it then appears an error :

> Could not execute statement. Cursor not open SQLCODE=-180, ODBC 3
>   State="34000"

The first table (tab1) will create, but other (tab2, tab3) tables not.

If I replace statement execute(sql) with select sql, script will work correctly.

Thanks in advance for your answer.

PX

Comment: You are aware, I hope, that with your current code, the individual statements could run in any order, since you have no `ORDER BY` in your cursor definition.

Comment: Yes, I know it. It doesn't matter, it's just an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IQ likes to close the cursor after the first commit.

You need to use the WITH HOLD clause (or something along those lines) to keeps the cursor open.

Comment: I probably should have clarified something about cursors in IQ, but I was distracted.  Anyways, HOLD cursors are very expensive inside IQ, because of the table versioning it can become a very large transaction.  Here's a few very short blurbs on IQ cursors/transactions to keep in mind: http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00170.1510/html/iqapgv1/X100766.htm

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you do it with while loop.using Cursor is overkill in these scenarios.
I am not familiar with sybase syntax but in SQL Server 2008 you can do like this

```
create table tab
(
  CreateSql varchar(250)
  ,ID int IDENTITY(1,1) 
)

insert into tab values ('create table tab1 (id int )')
insert into tab values ('create table tab2 (id int )')
insert into tab values ('create table tab3 (id int )')

DECLARE @max INT = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM tab) 
    ,@index int =1
    ,@sql varchar(255)


  while (@index<= @max  )
    begin           

      select @sql= createsql   from tab WHERE ID=@index

      execute(@Sql)  

      SET @index = @index+1
    end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! 
It is very good idea and probably I will use your code. But I still wondering why it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a sybase expert but it looks like you missing next on the fetch statement.

```
    fetch next cur into @sql
```

Comment: There is fetch below  execute(@Sql)